# Function with a size_t Template Parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm trying to understand the template function. The ultimate goal is to pass an entire array to a function. There seem to be many different ways to implement this but they all use the template function. Here's one of the simpler examples I've found...

```
template<size_t N>
void h(Sample (&arr)[N])
{
    size_t count = N; //N is 10, so would be count!
    //you can even do this now:
    //size_t count = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);  it'll return 10!
}
Sample arr[10];
h(arr); //pass : same as before!
```

I thought template<> was used to create a variable that could be used in place of int, float, char, etc.. what's the point of specifying the type (size_t), what does this do?

Comment: See [non-type template parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments).

Comment: "The ultimate goal is to pass an entire array to a function". Use std::array or std::vector.

Comment: @n.m. passing a `std::array` likely still needs the function to templated on the array length - so the question stays relevant even with that fix.

Answer (score 3):

The `size_t N` template parameter is a deduced integral value based upon the array size passed to the template function. Templates parameters can be

- non-type template parameter;
- type template parameter;
- template template parameter.

Reference: [Template Parameters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters).

Answer (score -1):

You can reuse the template for arrays of any size.